# Python get current class name without using function

Tags: python, classname

I am trying to extract the current class name without creating an object or a function.

For example:

```
class A:
    class_name = [getCurrentClassName]
    def function(self):
        print self.class_name
```

should print "A". However I don't know how to do that. With `class_name = __name__` I get all Packages as well ("outerPackage.innerPackage.A").

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: I'm curious why you need this

Comment: `type(self).__name__`?

Comment: @KlausD. That causes a NameError: self is not defined. Thanks though

Comment: Because you should be using `def function(self): print(type(self).__name__)`

Comment: @roganjosh For testing purposes. Since i need to create many testusers this would be a great way to differentiate each on. I could do it in a setup function but for finding errors in a test i can be useful to only run the setup function once for the first try and keep the setup users for other tries. That way i can save time.

Comment: the class name is already an attribute of a class object, why bother to set again?

Comment: Your explanation of what you're trying to do assumes too much context that may be obvious to you, but to anyone else reading is completely lost.  If you want to get the name of an object's class, use `self.__class__.__name__`.  If you just want the name of a class by itself, look at the `__name__` attribute of the class like `A.__class__` (this is exactly the same as doing `self.__class__.__name__` in a method on an instance of that class; `self.__class__` is just `A` itself).